# How to Install Ubuntu 14.10 alongside Windows 8.1 in Sony Vaio Laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, bios, vaio, sony

I was using Ubuntu for the past 7 years in my desktop computer.And now I got a new Sony Vaio Laptop.But still now I love to use Ubuntu.
I've downloaded Ubuntu 14.10 64 bit version to install in my Vaio. But its not loading the DVD when I try rebooting.
My Vaio is built in with Windows 8.1.
Any idea on how to Install Ubuntu 14.10 64bit version alongside Windows 8.1 ?

> Look at my Laptop Specifications.
>
> - Processor     : Intel i5
> - Architecture  : 64Bit
> - Current OS    : Windows 8.1
> - RAM           : 4GB
> - Brand         : Sony
> - Model         : SVF15319

Hope You can help.Please help me fixing this !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, your problem is orginated from BIOS preferences. Go to BIOS and do the followings:

- Go to BOOT label
- Replace Legacy BIOS with UEFI
- Save and Exit

After you did these, I think you can do dual boot easily.

Comment: I know this.But the problem is that there is no option to go to BIOS in a VAIO I think.
I've tried pressing F2 and F10 while loading.
But it just shows me the VAIO badge and on bottom a windows 8 style loader.
Not showing anything else

Comment: Couldn't even go to BIOS.Then how ?

Comment: Its impossible to not go to BIOS. Okay dont worry, we gonna find out a way

Comment: could you try to press f1, f2, f10, f12, del, esc on same time. Probably, you gonna find i am sure about that:) "CONSTANTLY"

Comment: Will it make any problems if I press these together ?

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: Thank you !
I will try doing it later.Because I'm going out !
Thank you as advance if this helps me !

Comment: ok. I say that because every computers have different bios combinations

Comment: Please Check this page : http://community.sony.com/t5/VAIO-Upgrade-Backup-Recovery/How-can-I-enter-bios-on-my-vaio-I-want-to-boot-from-the-cd-drive/m-p/60065#M1093

 Sony says to Do press the Assist button to go to bios !
I think this will work !
But thank you for your help !

Comment: I've checked out Sony's customer service website and found that I may use the ASSIST Button to turn on to get on to the BIOS !
I've tried it and worked.
It seems to be the current Boot mode is set to UEFI !
There is another option called Legacy !
Do I need to change any of that ?

Comment: I went to BIOS. There is current boot mode is setted as UEFI.
there is Legacy as an option.
Can you please help me ?  Which one to choose ?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I supposed you solved the problem. Well, You gonna choose UEFI

Comment: Then, setup an USB stick or CD as bootable disk.Probably it takes time. Restart your computer. Then, here you go! If you have any muddies point, please, let me know...:)

Comment: I have the bootable DVDs of different versions and varients like Linux mint Kubuntu and Mostly ubuntu !
And I know how to install too...
But when I went to the BIOS of my Sony Vaio, There are two modes, one is UEFI and the second one is Legacy in the category named Boot !
And my Boot mode is currently set as UEFI !
And I saw another related thing beneath of the boot mode item.
That is Boot from external device.I think that was the thing that restricted me from being booted from my Ubuntu installation DVD ! Because that was disabled !
But I've tried to disable that and rebooted. Not working

Comment: Have you ever tried to close secure boot?

Comment: I don't know how to disable secure boot. I couldn't yet install ubuntu alongside the windows 8.1 in my VAIO. Can you help please? How to disable secureboot?